# Running Ansible Playbook from Ubuntu (windows ubuntu terminal) on EC2 Instance

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to run my ansible playbook through ubuntu Terminal in  Windows on a EC2 Instance

I can log in with following ssh example to the EC2 Instance

```
ssh -i /path/to/my/pemfile.pem ubuntu@ipadress-of-my-EC2
```

with that command I successfully login to my EC2 Instance.

Now I want to run Ansible with following inventory file

```
[ec2_test]
hostnameofec2 ansible_host='ipadress-of-ec2' ansible_ssh_user='ubuntu' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/path/to/my/pemfile.pem'
```

When I run this in my command line

```
ansible-playbook /path/to/my/inventory test.yml -vvvv
```

I get the following output in the console:

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/mladen/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/mladen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) [GCC 7.4.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected <document start>

The error appears to be in '/mnt/d/GGstudio/Ansible/inventory/ggstudio/inventory': line 2, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

[ec2_test]
hostnameofec2 ansible_host='ipadress-of-ec2' ansible_ssh_user='ubuntu' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/path/to/my/pemfile.pem'
^ here
```

So I don't understand how the provided host list is empty when I assign the host in the inventory file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, forgot the -i parameter... sorry for spaming